# mobile, portable printing

Tags: printing, android, ipad, 3g, fax

A friend of mine is a contractor who wants me to help him go "high tech".  Right now, he calls the office several times a day asking for new work orders and then writes them down on a clipboard, so that he can check off the items when they are complete.  He was interested in having a small printer in his truck that would be connected via 3G so that the office could send work orders to the printer.  He also would not be opposed to using an iPad (or similar) with 3G or his Android phone as an intermediary.

- Are there printers that have 3G built-in? Just want to know, not asking for shopping advice.
- If not, can an iPad print directly to a wireless printer via 802.11 without the use of an access point?
- Would a celluar fax work in this scenario?

Comment: Why print anything at all? If he's alright with using a tablet, do it on the tablet.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic for Superuser. http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: [how to print from an Android phone](http://www.pcworld.com/article/212203/how_to_print_from_an_android_phone.html)

Comment: @Oliver: He has to give the check lists to other workers.

Answer (score 4):

A printer with internet printing (such as HP eprint printers) and a 3g router might work and would let the office just send a print job.

Or a printer that supports airprint can be printed to from the ipad.  You may need a portable wifi router in the truck for them to both connect to.